# If $S$ is a curve determined by $f(x,y)$, where $f$ is smooth in $\mathbb R^2$, then $f$ is identically zero on $S$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

What I wrote is what the textbook says when the author tries to explain an example such that a nonzero form on $M$ may restrict to the zero form on a submanifold $S$.

If $S$ is a smooth curve in $\mathbb R^2$ defined by the nonconstant function $f(x,y)$, then $df$ is a nonzero 1-form on $\mathbb R^2$, but since **since $f$  is identically zero on $S$**, $df$ is also identically zero on $S$.

I don't understand why the bolded text is true. $S$ can be written as: $S = \{(x,y,z) \mid z = f(x,y)\}$. However on $S$, there is no reason for $f(x,y)$ to be identically 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is just what you mean when you say that $S$ is a smooth curve defined by $f(x,y)$, isn't it? What you _should_ perhaps have said is that $S$ is a smooth curve defined by $f(x,y)=0$. (Note that $S$ is a curve in $\Bbb R^2$, not a surface in $\Bbb R^3$.)

Comment: $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ not $\mathbb{R}^3$. By _a curve determined by $f$_, we mean the zero set of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the second part just say that if $v$ is tangent to $S$, then $\mathrm{d}fv = 0$. On can see this by saying that $v = \sigma'(0)$ where $\sigma(t)$ is a local parametrization of $S$. Then $f\circ \sigma = 0$ by definition of $f$ and differentiating shows that $\mathrm{d}f\sigma'(0) = \mathrm{d}fv = 0$